# PostgreSQL select value and increment at once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a possible solution to the following. I have data stored in a table to keep track of a special increment number the customer wants in the DB. This is a special number they use internally.

What I would like to do is automatically increment this number in the table when I select it. So I don't have the problem of another transaction, from someone else using the system, using the same ID number.

So I want to select the current number and increment it by one at once so I don't have duplicates. How would I go about doing this if it is even possible?

Comment: With `increment it by one` you also want to **update** the existing value, right?

Comment: Why not use a sequence? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html  it doesn't suffer from number contention that other methods may if not properly developed.  For example, say two people go to select a record if both see the "Current" as 10, they both would then try and create 11...

Comment: UPDATE foo
    SET id=nextval('foo_sequence')
    WHERE ...
    RETURNING *

Comment: Can also be approached the other way around: first select the id column (sounds like a version_id column) upon read.  When an update is performed, add the clause `where version_id = :selected_version_id`. With a trigger on the table to update the `version_id` upon each update, concurrent transactions won't happen. The second person in will update 0 rows since the version_id no longer matches. You capture the 0 rows updated status to detect a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE the_table
SET the_column = the_column + 1
WHERE qualifier = X
RETURNING the_column;
```

Comment: What for the case where the qualifier returns 0 rows, and we want to insert with counter = 1 in that case?

Comment: Bit late, but you’d so an ‘insert on conflict set’ with a returning clause

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do the trick, with the caveat that it will return the new id rather than the old one:

```
UPDATE foo
SET id=nextval('foo_sequence')
WHERE ...
RETURNING *
```