# Rule or trigger to increment column's value on SELECT in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.4
How do I create rule or trigger to increment column's value (int4) by one each time when a row has been selected?
I've seen this:
[PostgreSQL select value and increment at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477870/postgresql-select-value-and-increment-at-once)
but it doesn't looks handy. I have queries, views and functions, which are selecting rows from the table. So, with this suggested solution, I would have to duplicate this query everywhere, which is not good approach.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Audit tracing? Some kind of usage counter?

Comment: i want to allow users to see views count

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned in your post this is the way to go:
[PostgreSQL select value and increment at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477870/postgresql-select-value-and-increment-at-once)

In Postgre there is no SELECT trigger that otherwise would come in handy in your case.

"SELECT does not modify any rows so you cannot create SELECT triggers. Rules and views are more appropriate in such cases."
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html